# Get DOM-element from $$watchers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

One can access a scope's $$watchers collection via

```
$scope.$$watchers
```

Is it possible, to get the DOM-Element, from the $$watchers array item?
I looked at the object via console.log and found the current value - but not the element which holds the value.

Comment: Your code shouldn't use that as it's an internal property of the framework (you could assume this might disappear in a future release). What are you trying to do exactly? Your question doesn't really make sense as there is no relation between a watched expression and a DOM element.

Comment: @floribon I want to remove all watchers from elements, that are not visible in the current scoll view and reattach them, when the element is visible again

Comment: Then you should ask that rather than a XY problem. The best way would be to remove the element from the DOM instead of targetting the watchers (with some filter or ng-if). Otherwise make your watchers return if they are not going to compute anything useful.